# GPRS module sendTCPData returns 403 Forbidden server error

Tags: http, arduino

I'm trying to fetch data from web server using Arduino Uno. I'm using SIM800L module to connect via GPRS. Following is the code I used to connect to web server.

```cpp
#include <gprs.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

char http_cmd[] = "GET canopussl.com/info.php HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
char buffer[512];

GPRS gprs;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  Serial.println("GPRS - HTTP Connection Test...");  
  gprs.preInit();
  while(0 != gprs.init()) {
     delay(1000);
     Serial.println("init error");
  }  
  while(!gprs.join("dialogbb")) {  //change "cmnet" to your own APN
      Serial.println("Error joining GPRS network");
      delay(2000);
  }
  // successful DHCP
  Serial.print("IP Address is ");
  Serial.println(gprs.getIPAddress());

  Serial.println("Init success, connecting to canopussl.com ...");

  if(0 == gprs.connectTCP("canopussl.com", 80)) {
      Serial.println("Successfully connected to canopussl.com!");
  }else{
      Serial.println("connect error");
      while(1);
  }

  Serial.println("waiting to fetch...");
  if(0 == gprs.sendTCPData(http_cmd))
  {      
    gprs.serialDebug();
  }

  gprs.closeTCP();
  gprs.shutTCP();
  Serial.println("close");  
}

void loop() {    

}
```

The output was this.

```
GPRS - HTTP Connection Test...
IP Address is 10.84.3.49
Init success, connecting to canopussl.com ...
Successfully connected to canopussl.com!
waiting to fetch...

HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
</body></html>

CLOSED
```

How I have to modify the HTTP header to receive the normal output from server?

Comment: `403 forbidden` is a response from the web server. Do you have access to this address?

Comment: Yes this is accessible via browser http://canopussl.com/info.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending the mandatory `Host` header.

Your HTTP request should look like:

```cpp
char http_cmd[] = "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: canopussl.com\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the guide. It works well. And you saved a lot of time.